# Reset password not working in Magento 2.4.5-p1

Tags: magento, magento2.4

The reset password is not working, I'm receiving the email, and reset link is working. After entering the new password and submit, it says that the password reset link has expired.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiNAL.png)
Please find screenshot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if in your theme you have overridden password_reset_confirmation.html

If yes then replace

```
<a href="{{var this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/createPassword/',[_query:[token:$customer.rp_token],_nosid:1])}}"
```

with

```
<a href="{{var this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/createPassword/',[_query:[id:$customer.id,token:$customer.rp_token],_nosid:1])}}"
```